# Minipage width to ignore its content

Tags: minipage

I have a piece of code which I want to use to align equations one next to another using `minipage`s. But there is a part of equation which I want to go below  the other equation.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum F_x &= ma \\
ma &= \sum F_x\\
ma &= -F_{tr}+F_{gx}\\
ma &= -F_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &=-F_{n}k_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &= -F_{g}\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &= -mg\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+mg \sin{\alpha}\\
a &= \frac{-mg\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+mg \sin{\alpha}}{m} = \frac{m (-g\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+g \sin{\alpha})}{m} = -g\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+g \sin{\alpha}\\
a &= -9,\,81\tfrac{m}{s^2}\cos{65^\circ}\cdot 0,\,2+9,\,81\tfrac{m}{s^2} \sin{65^\circ} = 8,\,06\tfrac{m}{s^2}\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum F_y &= 0\\
+F_n - F_{gy}&=0\\
+F_n - F_{g}\cos \alpha&=0\\
F_n &= F_{g}\cos \alpha
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
```

And this is what I get when compiling:

[image]

If I decrease first `minipage` width to `0.3` my other `minipage` won't jump a bit to the left as the content of first `minipage` automatically seems to adjust `minipage`'s width. Is there any way I can make the equation in the **second** `minipage` to appear above the longer part of equation in **first** `minipage`.

---

**EDIT:**

One more question arized and this topic is the right one. I would like to align an image which i put in 1st minipage and an equation which i put in a second minipage so that both would be aligned at the top. I used `[t]` parameter for the minipage, but it wont seem to do this. How can make the equation jump upward?

The code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{../slike-v/6.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum M_A&=0\\
+M_{F_g} - M_F &= 0\\
F_g x - D r_1 &= 0\\
mgx - Fl\cos{\alpha} &= 0\\
F &= \frac{mgx}{l\cos{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
```

And the result that i get:

[image]

How do i make equation jump upward to the desired place? **Why does it even jump down?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather hacky, but seems to work. I used `\rlap` to smash the left minipage to zero width, and then put the result in another minipage to get the vertical alignment right. You can fine-tune the spacing by adjusting the `\hspace{60mm}` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\rlap{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum F_x &= ma \\
ma &= \sum F_x\\
ma &= -F_{tr}+F_{gx}\\
ma &= -F_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &=-F_{n}k_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &= -F_{g}\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+F_{g} \sin{\alpha}\\
ma &= -mg\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+mg \sin{\alpha}\\
a &= \frac{-mg\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+mg \sin{\alpha}}{m} = \frac{m (-g\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+g \sin{\alpha})}{m} = -g\cos{\alpha}k_{tr}+g \sin{\alpha}\\
a &= -9,\,81\tfrac{m}{s^2}\cos{65^\circ}\cdot 0,\,2+9,\,81\tfrac{m}{s^2} \sin{65^\circ} = 8,\,06\tfrac{m}{s^2}\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{60mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum F_y &= 0\\
+F_n - F_{gy}&=0\\
+F_n - F_{g}\cos \alpha&=0\\
F_n &= F_{g}\cos \alpha
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update.** Your second code snippet can be fixed as shown below.

- Again, there's nothing particularly principled going on here, I just added `minipage`s and `\rlap`s until it looked right!
- I added the `[demo]` option because I don't have your image file on my computer, hence the black box.
- The `[t]` options for the minipages aren't enough on their own, because the included graphic is (by default) aligned on its bottom. To make the graphic align on its top, I use the `calc` package and a trick described [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-topgraph).

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\raisebox{1ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=90mm]{../slike-v/6.pdf}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{30mm}
\rlap{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sum M_A&=0\\
+M_{F_g} - M_F &= 0\\
F_g x - D r_1 &= 0\\
mgx - Fl\cos{\alpha} &= 0\\
F &= \frac{mgx}{l\cos{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between `\llap` and `\rlap`?

Comment: To quote [Alexander Perlis](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf): "The former
aligns the smashed box at the right end of the ink
(so that we end up with a “left overlap”), while the
latter aligns the smashed box at the left end (resulting in a “right overlap”)."